# Suppose we have a homomorphism $f:G\to\Bbb Z$ for a finite group $G$. Prove that $f(g)=0$ for all $g$ in $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

Suppose we have a homomorphism from $G$, a finite group, to $\Bbb Z$, the set of integers, $f:G\to\Bbb Z$. To prove that $f(g)=0$ for all $g$ in $G$, what I did is defined an isomorphism - $h:G/\ker(f)\to{\rm im}(f).$ (First isomorphism theorem.)

Now, ${\rm im}(f)$ looks like any subset $m\Bbb Z$ of $\Bbb Z.$ Since $h$ is a 1-1 correspondence and maps the identities, we conclude that $m$ must be $0$ for this to hold, which means that the element going to identity is $\ker(f).$

But I am having trouble proving $\ker(f) = G$, I don't seem to notice what I'm missing. (If $\ker(f) = G$, then the problem is solved.)

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: HInt:  Take $g\in G$.  If $G$ has order $n$ then $g^n=e$.  Suppose that $f(g)=a$.  Deduce that $na=0$.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 4):

*Hint:* The order of $f(g)$ divides the order of $g$ for all $g\in G$. Note that $\Bbb Z$ is torsion-free.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose for the sake of contradiction that there is some $g \in G$ for which $0 \neq f(g) \in \mathbb{Z}$. Next, consider the sequence:

$$f(g^1), f(g^2), f(g^3), \ldots$$

for which no two terms are the same: if $f(g) > 0$ then this is a monotonically increasing sequence, and if $f(g) < 0$ then this is a monotonically decreasing sequence. In any event, this sequence has no repeating elements.

However, $G$ is finite, which means $|G| = n$ for some positive integer $n < \infty$.

Then, $f(g^n) = f(e_G) = 0$, which contradicts the non-repetition of the sequence described above. Thus, our supposition was incorrect, and it must be that $f(g) = 0$ for all $g \in G$.

Answer (score 1):

$\Bbb Z$ doesn't have any non-trivial finite subgroups: every non-trivial subgroup is infinite cyclic.   But $G/\rm ker(f)\cong f(G)\le\Bbb Z$ is a subgroup. That's the homomorphic image of a group is a group.

---

For a generalization of the first statement,  any subgroup of a free abelian group on $n$ generators is free abelian on at most $n$ generators, hence infinite (or trivial).  This is a theorem of Dedekind.  You can find it in Lang's *Algebra*.  Zorn's lemma is used.

Or, any subgroup of a free group is free: Nielsen-Schrier.  This came later.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose (towards a contradiction) that there exists $g\in G$ with $f(g) \neq 0$. Then, since $G$ is finite, $|G|=n<\infty$. Then the order of $g$ must divide $n$. In any case, $g^n = 1_G$, so $f(g^n) = f(1_G) = 0$. But this means that $f(g^n) = [f(g)]^n = 0$. Since $f(g)$ is an integer, we require that some nonzero integer $c$ exists such that $c^n=0$. But such an integer does not exist. Contradiction!

Comment: Note that the operation of $\Bbb Z$ is *addition* and so it would be $$f(g^n) = n[f(g)]= 0$$ and $$nc=0$$ instead.

Comment: Well, $nc$ is $c^n$ under addition, but I suppose your notation is clearer.